# How to color output with outs()

Tags: colors, terminal, llvm

Can I color the terminal output using outs() ? 
it's defined into raw_ostream.cpp

example:

```
outs() <<"I would this RED";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
outs().changeColor(raw_ostream::RED) << "I would this RED\n";
outs().resetColor();
```